# OS specific directories for binary generated by Electron Builder

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

Electron Builder has output directory field

```
"directories": {
  "output": "releases",
  "buildResources": "dist"
},
```

But this is just single folder for 3 platform specific build(Mac, Windows and Linux)

I need different directories for respective platform with sub directory for "Arch"
something like this-

```
releases
       | windows
       |      | 64bit
       |      | 32bit
       |
       | mac
       |   | 64bit
       |   | 32bit
       |
       | linux
       |     | 64bit
       |     | 32bit
```

How can I create different directories for specific OS while creating distributable with electron builder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found solution using [File Macros support in electron builder](https://www.electron.build/file-patterns#file-macros)

We can specify platform and arch macro in output directory path (package.json)-

```
"directories": {
    "output": "releases/${platform}/${arch}"
 },
```

This will automatically create folders for respective platform and sub-folder for arch